# Kafka consumer takes a long time to get the message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I wrote function test for my system on Java

**Test scenario**
In test I create two topics: "topicFunc1", "2_1".
The producer from the test sends a message to the topic "topicFunc1", the consumer from my system receives a message, some actions are performed and the producer of the system sends a message to the topic "2_1". The consumer in the test tries to get messages from the topic "2_1" and this happens only after 3-4 seconds. But when I send a message to the topic "topicFunc1" it is performed instantly.

My problem is that the consumer from the test cannot quickly get the message from the topic.
For analysis, I used the test log, as well as the wireshark utility

**Log from test:**

```
[2022.08.29 10:55:48.094] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaProducerUtils.publishMessagesString() at line 47]        Send message "{"subsId":3}" to kafka topic: topicFunc1
[2022.08.29 10:55:48.156] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaConsumerUtilsWithConstructor.getMessages() at line 43]       execute poll())
[2022.08.29 10:55:48.156] [DEBUG] [System_Processor] [kafkaApi.KafkaStringConsumer.processRecord() at line 24]      Received message: value = {"subsId":3}, topic = topicFunc1
[2022.08.29 10:55:48.235] [DEBUG] [System_Processor] [kafkaApi.KafkaSimpleProducer.produce() at line 46]        sent record( message={"result":"1_1"}) meta(partition=0, offset=0) to topic = 2_1
[2022.08.29 10:55:48.235] [DEBUG] [System] [kafkaApi.EpmKafkaConsumer.commitOffsets() at line 182]      Consumer : epm.1, committing the offsets : {topicFunc1-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
[2022.08.29 10:55:49.156] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaConsumerUtilsWithConstructor.getMessages() at line 45]       look at list messages!)
[2022.08.29 10:55:49.156] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaConsumerUtilsWithConstructor.getMessages() at line 43]       execute poll())
[2022.08.29 10:55:50.172] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaConsumerUtilsWithConstructor.getMessages() at line 45]       look at list messages!)
[2022.08.29 10:55:50.172] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaConsumerUtilsWithConstructor.getMessages() at line 43]       execute poll())
[2022.08.29 10:55:51.187] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaConsumerUtilsWithConstructor.getMessages() at line 45]       look at list messages!)
[2022.08.29 10:55:51.187] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaConsumerUtilsWithConstructor.getMessages() at line 43]       execute poll())
[2022.08.29 10:55:51.218] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaConsumerUtilsWithConstructor.getMessages() at line 45]       look at list messages!)
[2022.08.29 10:55:51.218] [DEBUG] [main] [httpApi.utils.kafka.KafkaConsumerUtilsWithConstructor.lambda$getMessages$0() at line 49]      record.value() = {"result":"1_1"})
```

The message from my system was sent at 10:55:48.235.
The consumer received the message at 10:55:51.218

**WireShark log**

```
№        Source           Destination   Protocol     length         info                          time utc
2638    ipMyServer      ipKafkaServer   Kafka        238        Kafka Produce v7 Request        2022-08-29 10:55:48,233929
2639    ipKafkaServer   ipMyServer      Kafka        109        Kafka Produce v7 Response       2022-08-29 10:55:48,238583
2891    ipMyServer      ipKafkaServer   Kafka        101        Kafka OffsetFetch v5 Request    2022-08-29 10:55:51,197174
2892    ipKafkaServer   ipMyServer      Kafka        101        Kafka OffsetFetch v5 Response   2022-08-29 10:55:51,201233
2903    ipMyServer      ipKafkaServer   Kafka        109        Kafka Offsets v5 Request        2022-08-29 10:55:51,210409
2904    ipKafkaServer   ipMyServer      Kafka        105        Kafka Offsets v5 Response       2022-08-29 10:55:51,213951
2905    ipMyServer      ipKafkaServer   Kafka        147        Kafka Fetch v11 Request         2022-08-29 10:55:51,214318
2907    ipKafkaServer   ipMyServer      Kafka        190        Kafka Fetch v11 Response        2022-08-29 10:55:51,218333
```

The Kafka producer send Request at 10:55:48,233929. 
Kafka Fetch Request was sent at 10:55:51,214318. 
If we look at the "Log from the test", we will see that the first poll() was executed at 10:55:48.156, then at 10:55:49.156, 10:55:50.172, 10:55:51.187. But in "Wireshark Log" the request was sent only at 10:55:51.
**Why is this happening? What could be the reason for the delay?**

Comment: Does your system producer instantly flushes the message out? If not, it could be sitting in buffer for some time before actually getting transferred to kafka. Also, what is the poll duration of your test consumer?

Comment: @RishabhSharma If you look at the logs that I provided, then the producer  sends a request immediately. The duration of the consumer poll is 1 second.